# Scala - how to convert Object to List[Object]

Tags: json, scala, predictionio

I have an Object testCat having value `List(123, 456, 789)` and I would like to convert this Object to `List[Object]` in scala. When I use `asInstanceOf`, I got the error:

```
DataSource.scala:310: T0 does not take parameters
[ERROR] [Console] [error]
var testCat = eachMultiCat.asInstanceOf(List[Object])
[ERROR] [Console] [error]
```

Can anybody help me with this issue? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Your syntax for using `asInstanceOf` is incorrect - it isn't a function taking a type as parameter, but a parameter-less function that needs a type specification. Basically, replace the parentheses "`()`" with square brackets: `.asInstanceOf[List[Object]]`

Comment: Dear Shadowlands, I encountered the same issue. The object is comming from parsing JSon, anyway I already found another way to parse the list. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

```
.asInstanceOf[List[Object]]
```

with *square* brackets, as it is a type parameter.

Still wondering, why a conversion from Object to List of Objects is necessary. Smells fishy!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
val obj1: Object = List(123, 456, 789)
println(obj1)

val obj2 = obj1.asInstanceOf[List[Object]]
println(obj2)

val obj3 = obj1.asInstanceOf[List[Int]]
println(obj3)

// cant do: obj1.map(_*2)
// can't do: obj2.map(_*2)

// this works
println(obj3.map(_*2))
```

OUTPUT:

```
List(123, 456, 789)
List(123, 456, 789)
List(123, 456, 789)
List(246, 912, 1578)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve my problem, this is all of working code

```
val multiCategoryOne =
    for { JString(x) <- (content \\ ancesstorCategories").children} yield x

var multiCategoryMany:List[Object] = Nil
if (multiCategoryOne == Nil) {
    // multiple items in cart
    val elements = (content \\ "ancesstorCategories").children
    for ( acct <- elements ) {
        val eachMultiCat = for { JString(x) <- acct} yield x
        multiCategoryMany = multiCategoryMany ::: List(eachMultiCat)
    }

} else {
    // one item in cart
    multiCategoryMany = multiCategoryMany ::: List(multiCategoryOne)
}
```